# Create a folder in a specific one Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I've been looking for ages in stackoverflow but couldn't find the answer.

I'm looking for creating a folder in a specific folder but cannot find how.

At the moment, I create the folder and a file inside it but would like to change the path.

```
  var Folder = DriveApp.createFolder(curDate + ' ' + customerCompany).createFile(blobs[0]);
```

Where,

> `curDate + ' ' + customerCompany` is the name of my file
>
> `blobs[0]` is the PDF that I create

I was wondering how and where to put the path of the folder.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a little convoluted. You have to get the folder you want to put the folder into and then put it in that folder and then add your file to the inserted folder:

```
var firstFolder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('firstFolderName').next();
var secondFolder = firstFolder.createFolder('secondFolderName');
secondFolder.createFile(blobs[0]);
```

Google doesn't really do file paths, every folder and file has a unique ID, which is why you can have many files and folders of the same name in the same locations. Which also means you need to be aware that having folders with the same names can scatter your files all over the place with the above code.